# Ubuntu network mounts intermittently stop working

Tags: networking, mount, sudo, samba, cifs

As the title says, some of the mounts work all the time, and some I need to do a restart for them to work.  They always show they're mounted on my GUI but they do not work.  Like I said, a restart makes everything work great; any ideas?

Thank you

Here is how I have them mounting

Movies:

```
//192.168.xx.xxx/data/media/movies /home/mark/plex/movies cifs user,rw,credentials=/root/.smbclient 0 0
```

TV:

```
//192.168.xx.xxx/data/media/tv /home/mark/plex/tv cifs user,rw,credentials=/root/.smbclient 0 0
```

Comment: How exactly do you see "they do not work"?

Comment: They do not lead into PLEX, also, I’m running Unbutu with GUI. So when I click on the folders where it shows them being mounted and then I get an error and nothin shows up.

Comment: What do you see if you try to enter the folders in terminal? Do you see anything interesting in `journalctl -r`?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect what is happening is fstab is being read by the system before the network stack is operational on the Ubuntu client so there is no way to connect to the server.

There are two general methods to remedy this. Both of them result in shares being mounted "on demand" when needed and not automatically:

**[1] Keep the mount point under your home directory but add the "noauto" option:**

```
//192.168.xx.xxx/data/media/movies /home/mark/plex/movies cifs user,noauto,rw,credentials=/root/.smbclient 0 0
```

*The share will mount only when you use the launcher of the side panel of your file manager first.*

**[2] Change the mount point to be under /mnt and use the systemd automounter:**

```
//192.168.xx.xxx/data/media/movies /mnt/plex/movies cifs user,x-systemd.automount,rw,credentials=/root/.smbclient 0 0
```

*The share will mount when the /mnt/plex/movies folder is accessed.*

After you make any changes like this to fstab concerning network assets remember to make systemd happy by running:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload

sudo systemctl restart remote-fs.target
```

***Note***: *You can try to use the x-systemd.automount option with the mount point under your home directory but another process ( udisks2 ) interferes with the automounter causing it to try to mount too soon. Mount points somewhere other than your home directory or /media would be better*

Comment: I did the option 2, and it worked well, I figured out what the issue was.  Whenever I added an audiobook from my pc directly to the file via SMB, for some reason Unbutu didnt like that and would lose the connection.  After option 2 everything worked well.  Thank you Morbius 1!